# Python 3: UnboundLocalError - local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, function

I get the error

```
How often? 33
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "main.py", line 17, in main
    won += 1
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'won' referenced before assignment
```

when I try to run the following code:

```
teller = 0
throw = int(input('How often?'))
won = 0 
    def main():
        pricedoor = round (3 * np.random.rand() + 0.5)
        if pricedoor == 4 : pricedoor = 3
        choicedoor = round (3 * np.random.rand() + 0.5)
        if choicedoor == 4 : choicedoor = 3
        sheepdoor = mf.quizmasteropens(pricedoor, choicedoor)
        #choicedoor = choicedoor

        if choicedoor == pricedoor:   
          won += 1

    while teller < throw :
        main()
        teller = teller + 1
```

How can I fix this problem? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

To make this work, you need to move the assignment to `won` inside `main()`:

```
def main():
   won = 0 
   ...
```

If you want to make the value of `won` available outside `main()`, I'd suggest returning it from the function like so:

```
def main():
   won = 0 
   ...
   return won
```

If you do this, the caller would be able to assign the value to its own variable (which may or may not be called `won` - that's up to you):

```
won = main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Scope of variable won is not defined for main(). If you want to use won you need to defined as :

```
def main():
    won = 0
```